# Reuse attributes of an object in different units

Tags: class, delphi

I want to reuse the attributes of an object in a different unit.

On form1 I have initialized the object by calling the create procedure. I then assign a value to fUserID using the set procedure. Now on the next form, Form2, I want to call the getUserID function to retrieve the attribute's value obtained in the previous form.

I tried recreating the object but the value is lost. For example, if I assign the ID 2, when the function GetUSerID is called in the new unit, without recreating the object it gives an error. When the object is recreated it returns nil.

```
unit clsUser_U;

interface
type
  TUser = class(TObject)
    private
      FUserID : integer ;
    public
      constructor Create ;
      procedure setUserID(iID : integer) ;
      Function getUserID : Integer ;
    end;

implementation

{ TUser }

constructor TUser.Create;
begin

end;

function TUser.getUserID: Integer;
begin
  Result := FUserID ;
end;

procedure TUser.setUserID(iID: integer);
begin
  FUserID := iID ;
end;

end.
```

Form1 looks as follow:

```
unit Form1_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  clsUser_u, form2_u;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnNextForm: TButton;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNextFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    objUser : TUser ;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnNextFormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ShowModal ;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  objUser := TUser.Create ;
  objUser.setUserID(2);
end;

end.
```

Form2 looks as follow:

```
unit Form2_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  clsUser_U;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    lbl1: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    objUser : TUser ;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lbl1.Caption := inttostr(objUser.getUserID);
end;

end.
```

Delphi gives the error access violation.
How do I increase the lifetime of the object?

Comment: Nothing in this code results in an access violation. The access violation is caused by the other code, the code that you didn't show us. As for the lifetime of an object's state, well the state lives as long as the object. If you want to create and object and have its state persist, don't destroy it. Keep hold of that instance. Most likely you just need to spend some time with a beginner book on Delphi programming, or OOP programming in general. It looks like you haven't grasped the concept of lifetime yet.

Comment: You don't show how TUsers is used, either in Form1 or how you are trying to use it in Form2. We might guess, but our guesses might be wrong. pleas eread [MCVE] and include you sources. The answer will be relatively simple once we have this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still don't show a proper minimal example, that is something we could compile and reproduce your problem, but it is fairly clear what your problem is. There are two `objUser` objects, one owned by `Form1`, and one owned by `Form2`. You want to access the one from `Form1` in `Form2`, so you must reference `Form1`, something like this

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lbl1.Caption := IntToStr(Form1.objUser.getUserID);
end;
```

That assumes, of course, that `objUser` is globally visible in `Form1`, which it might not be, but you don't show enough for us to know. Also, `Form1` needs to be visible to `Form2`, but again you don't show us enough to know whether it is or not. That is why you need to show us as little as possible to show the fault, but enough for us to be able to reproduce your problem exactly.